# Android Menus and Sub-Menus

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-menu

I'm having trouble creating a radio-button sub-menu that is shown when a menu item from the options menu that appears when a user presses the menu button is selected. This is what I have so far:

```
// Expand the options menu when the user taps their menu button
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch item.getItemId() {
        case R.id.expandRadioMenu:
            // Show the sub-menu and collapse the initial menu
            return true;
    }
}
```

The XML of `res/menu/menu.xml` is as follows:

```
<menu 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:visible="true" 
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:checkable="false" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_mark" 
        android:id="@+id/expandRadioMenu" 
        android:title="Select" 
        android:titleCondensed="select">
        <menu>
        <group 
            android:enabled="true" 
            android:visible="false" 
            android:checkableBehavior="single" 
            android:id="@+id/radio">
            <item 
                android:enabled="true" 
                android:visible="true" 
                android:title="Foo" 
                android:titleCondensed="Foo" 
                android:id="@+id/foo">
            </item>
            <item 
                android:enabled="true" 
                android:visible="true" 
                android:title="Bar" 
                android:titleCondensed="Bar" 
                android:id="@+id/bar">
            </item>
        </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not particularly appealing, but have you tried moving the sub menu into a separate .xml file? I've seen it work before, but it's not a terribly hopeful solution. I suppose it might further identify the problem though.

Comment: The problem isn't with the XML, rather, I'm just trying to show the menu.

Comment: Basically, I just need that particular [sub]menu to appear when the user selects "Select" from the options menu, and hide when they make a selection.